# permission error for GCP logging router sink update

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, export, python-logging

When calling `sink.reload()`, I am getting permission error. `403 The caller does not have permission`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
def update_sink(creds, sink_name, filter_):
    logging_client = logging.Client(credentials=creds)

    sink = logging_client.sink(sink_name)
    sink.reload()

    sink.filter_ = filter_
    print("Updated sink {}".format(sink.name))

    response = sink.update()

    return response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Scope
    # "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    # "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only",
    # "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects",
    # "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly",
    # "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute",
    # "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudkms",
    # "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub",
    # "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.read",
    # "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
    # "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.admin"
    creds = {} # OAuth Credentials with above scope
    sink_name = "<sink path with project>"
    filter_ = "<filter>"
    
    response = update_sink(creds, sink_name, filter_)
    
    print(response)
```

Comment: Are you able to perform any operations on the log sink in question ? what API method are you using ?

Comment: @Wojtek_B I was able to create the same sink using `logging_client.create_sink` method. Behind the scenes, it uses https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/projects.sinks/update

Comment: If you found the solution to your question please post it as an answer so the community can benefit from it.

Comment: @Wojtek_B Definitely, will do. Not able to figure out what could be the issue here. From a permissions perspective, i have added logging.writer, logging.admin both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, one of the mistakes in my earlier program was that project was not passed as part of `Client` initialization.

Also, `sink.reload()` is not needed. One can directly update the sink without calling `reload()` as well.

Here's the working code:

```
logging_client = logging.Client(project=project_id, credentials=self.creds)

sink = logging_client.sink(sink_name)

sink.filter_ = filter_

sink.destination = destination

response = sink.update(unique_writer_identity=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are routing logs from project to sink , then service account/account running code need "Logging Admin" role on project.
Please verify if service account running code have Logging admin role to modify/update sink.

Comment: Running code has "Logging Admin" role on the project. One of the mistakes i did was around initialization of the logging Client. I have added an answer with the running code.